# Bootstrap меню, картинка на вверху ссылки

Tags: bootstrap

Всем привет. Не подскажите часть кода HTML и CSS как сделать меню вот так, чтобы картинка была наверху ссылки.

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Палитра</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background: #0c7b86;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom a {
  color: #fff;
}

.ico {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="ico">
              <img src="http://www.newdesignfile.com/postpic/2012/06/black-white-home-icon_280130.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
            <span>Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="ico">
              <img src="http://www.newdesignfile.com/postpic/2012/06/black-white-home-icon_280130.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
            <span>Page 1</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="ico">
              <img src="http://www.newdesignfile.com/postpic/2012/06/black-white-home-icon_280130.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
            <span>Page 2</span>
          </a>
        </li> 
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="ico">
              <img src="http://www.newdesignfile.com/postpic/2012/06/black-white-home-icon_280130.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
            </span>
            <span>Page 3</span>
          </a>
        </li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav {
    padding: 0;
}
.nav > li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}

.nav > li a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.nav > li a:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -23px;
    width: 46px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) 0 0;
    text-align: center;   
}
.nav > li:nth-of-type(2) a:before{    
    width: 43px;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) -47px 0;
}
.nav > li:nth-of-type(3) a:before{
    width: 43px;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) -91px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Палитра</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Палитра</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Палитра</a></li>     
</ul>
```